# increase field count when conflict on insert

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table

"phone_number_info"

```
id  uuid
country character
phone_number    text
page_views  bigint
```

I have the following query which is supposed to insert a row into the table, and if it already exists, increase the page_views count

```
INSERT INTO phone_number_info (country, phone_number) VALUES('us', '1234567890') 
ON CONFLICT (country, phone_number) 
DO UPDATE SET phone_number_info.page_views = (phone_number_info.page_views + 1);
```

When executing the query above, I get the following message

```
Error in query: ERROR: column "phone_number_info" of relation "phone_number_info" does not exist
LINE 3: DO UPDATE SET phone_number_info.page_views = (phone_number_i...
```

What is wrong with the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column identifiers in the `SET` clauses cannot be not qualified with the table name - they always refer to the updated table. So use

```
INSERT INTO phone_number_info (country, phone_number) VALUES('us', '1234567890') 
ON CONFLICT (country, phone_number) 
DO UPDATE SET page_views = (phone_number_info.page_views + 1);
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```